# How to move focus in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I wonder if there is anyway to change focus from the current control and move it to other control in WPF on TabIndex assigned controls.

Example
I have controls with TabIndex 1 to 5, is there a way to jumb the focus from 1 to 5 ?

```
<TextBox TabIndex="1" Focusable = "true" LostFocus="test_LostFocus"/>
<TextBox TabIndex="2" Focusable = "true"/>
...
<TextBox TabIndex="5" Focusable = "true" name="LastControl"/>
```

.

```
private void test_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  LastControl.Focus();
}
```

I tried  `Keyboard.Focus()` and `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement()` but no luck.

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you calling the `Focus` methods and are you calling it from a background thread?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `LostFocus` event? The user may have clicked away from the textbox onto another control. Would you rather just check if the user pressed `tab`/`enter` and only set focus then?

Comment: I'm doing it on `tab` I just left out that part to simplify the question.

Comment: In that case, use the `KeyDown` event and handle it yourself (as shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply handle the `KeyDown` event for the textboxes and set focus there. Since you're using `Tab`, let the control know you'll handle it by setting `e.Handled = true`, which will stop the default `tab` action of jumping to the control with the next `TabIndex`.

```
private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        LastControl.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, `KeyDown` is a better way to go (lostfocus will cause weird behaviors such as the user specifically clicking on the second control and the focus goes to the last one instead)...

Make sure you set the `e.Handled` to true though..!

This will work:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            LastControl.Focus();
        }
 }
```

Where the deceleration of the textbox should be something like this:

```
<TextBox TabIndex="1" Focusable = "true" KeyDown="TextBox1_KeyDown"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible WPF answer, non-programmatic:

`Ctrl+Tab` / `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`

Possible WPF answer, programmatic:

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^{TAB}");` /

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^+{TAB}");`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15621425/10789707