# How simulate CTRL+V keystrokes (paste) using C#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, paste

How can we simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keys (paste) using C#?

I have a textbox that hasn't a id for access, for example `textbox1.Text = someValue` won't work here.
I want to fill that textbox (from clipboard) by clicking on it. For some reasons we exactly need simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, mean we cannot use external libraries like [inputsimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).

Comment: More information needed - are you able to subclass the textbox? Are you in Silverlight, WinForms or WPF? Why are you unable to gain a reference to the textbox?

Comment: @Alex G i am working with webbrowser control in a winform and after navigate to an specific page i can not access goal textbox in webbrowser by it's id.

Comment: if your textbox is in the webbrowser this is not at all a winforms problem, it's all about HTML scripting

Comment: How are you finding the textbox? Can you get a handle to the textbox window? That would be a better way to insert text than emulating keystrokes.

Comment: i am clicking on that textbox by simulating mouse position and it's click. i really want to learn how can we simulate ctrl+v with c# language dear Jonathan Wood

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Character vs key

`%` => `alt` , `+` => `shift` and `^` is used for `ctrl` key

**Original Answer:**

Simulation of single modifier key with another key is explained below
**Step1:** Focus the textBox, on which you want to perform two keys and then **Step2:** send the key for example control-v will be sent like `"^{v}"`. Here is the code

```
target_textBox.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
```

`target_textBox.Focus();` is needed only when target textbox is not focused at the time of sending key

**Update: For sending three keys** (two modifying keys plus other key) like to achieve `ctrl shift F1` you will send following

`^+{F1}`

[Microsoft Docs Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_SendKeys_Send_System_String_)

Comment: thanks for the answer dear Sami, what about shift+home and shift+end?

Comment: @MoonLight - Here's a link with a bunch of useful information about all the different combinations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you are talking about sending those keys then I think `"+{home}"` `"+{end}"` would work

Comment: Note: If you want to use this outside of a WinForm context, e.g. in LinqPad, you will need `SendKeys.SendWait("^{v}");` to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you override the TextBox OnClick event than when the event is called, set the Text property to Clipboard.GetText()

Like:

```
private void textBox1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
        textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText ();
}
```

Comment: I wanted to vote you up, for I came to know a thing which I did not know, but i m sorry it is not working for me, have u tried it?

Comment: Have you added that to the TextBox's Click event?

Comment: Sorry I missed the assignment and just used `Clipboard.GetText ();` but now its working with any event (not only for click) as it should..

Answer (score 1):

This function is already built in: [TextBoxBase.Paste()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.paste%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
textbox1.Paste();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the language in the operating system is not English, this option may not work:

```
SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
```

Then try this option:

```
SendKeys.Send("+{INSERT}");
```

Answer (score 0):

some JS do not permit to change value in usual way

```
inputList[21].SetAttribute("value", txtEMail.Text);
```

you should try something like this:

```
inputElement.InvokeMember("focus");
inputElement.InvokeMember("click"); //sometimes helpfull
Clipboard.SetDataObject(txtEMail.Text);
SendKeys.Send("^(v)");
```

//but not "^{v}"