# How do I unselect a button in a control template?

Tags: wpf

I have an OK button that accepts data input, but the user can change some data and press it again. Each press saving a particular configuration.

I want the selection on the OK button to go away, so that the user knows it's been accepted.

Ideally, I would like a pure WPF solution.

**Update: some code**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MapCutIconsTemplate">
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <controls:ImageButton Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
                              Content="OK"
                              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                              Command="{Binding AcceptPositionCommand}" 
                              Source="{DynamicResource OkIcon}" 
                              Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColour}"/>

        <controls:ImageButton Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
                              Content="Back"
                              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                              Command="{Binding BackCommand}" 
                              Source="{DynamicResource BackIcon}" 
                              Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColour}"/>

    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I would like to move selection from OK button to Back button, once OK button is clicked.

**Update2: getting closer**

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
```

this gets me the button that has been pressed, passed in as a parameter to the Command function. What I really need is the other button object.

**Solution:**

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CutBack}"
```

proposed by @VS1.

Comment: Can you be more clear, give a code example, or what you tried at least please

Comment: A `button` accepting data input?

Comment: You are looking for CanExecute on your ICommand for the button in your ViewModel (This will be your 'pure' WPF (MVVM) approach)

Comment: You should read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the Help Center.

Comment: Krishna: I am indeed using ICommand, but I don't want to disable the button after it's clicked, just move focus to another button.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to move focus to another button once it has been pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move focus in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587649/how-to-move-focus-in-wpf)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587649/how-to-move-focus-in-wpf

Comment: @AlessandroRossi That question doesn't really relate to templates. See update2, in my question.

Comment: Can you try to change: `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=backButton}"` and give `Name="backButton"` for your backbutton and then in Command OnExecute for AcceptPosition button, do: `(parameter as button).Focus();`

Comment: @VS1 This works for me. Propose it as an answer and I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `xaml` with below code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MapCutIconsTemplate">
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <controls:ImageButton Name="acceptButton" 
                          Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
                          Content="OK"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          Command="{Binding AcceptPositionCommand}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=backButton}" 
                          Source="{DynamicResource OkIcon}" 
                          Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColour}"/>

        <controls:ImageButton Name="backButton" 
                          Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
                          Content="Back"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          Command="{Binding BackCommand}" 
                          Source="{DynamicResource BackIcon}" 
                          Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColour}"/>

    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And, your *ViewModel's AcceptPositionCommand.OnExecute* to include below line:

```
(parameter as Button).Focus(); //Will move focus to Back Button
```